# Wp mwnu not works at all

Tags: wp-admin

I've try to make wordpress theme but have a big problem with navbar.
when i try to make nav list after save my menu all the titles will disappear and all the links will gone! PLUS when I make dropdown items after save and refresh my page in admin panel all the items i've made under other items will jump out as parent item!

How can I fix this? any idea?

This is my code on `functions.php`

```
// Register Navigation Menus
function newborn_navigation_menus() {

    $locations = array(
        'Primary' => __( 'header-menu', 'newborn' ),
    );
    register_nav_menus( $locations );

}
```

And this is the code on my `header.php`

```
<nav>
          <ul class="hide-on-med-and-down">
            <?php wp_nav_menu(); ?>
          </ul>
          <ul id="slide-out" class="side-nav">
            <?php wp_nav_menu(); ?>
          </ul>
          <a href="#" data-activates="slide-out" class="button-collapse"><i class="mdi-navigation-menu"></i></a>
        </nav>
```

Here is an image of what will happen in my admin panel: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZXogn.jpg

Comment: None of the code you've posted is the problem. Try disabling all plugins and/or switching to a default theme, and test to see if the issue still occurs.

Comment: with twentyfifteen theme the same thing happened!

Comment: What about all plugins deactivated?

Comment: all deactivated

Comment: This is a really odd case. If after switching to a default theme, deactivating all plugins, and *then* creating a new menu, you still get the error, I can only suggest reinstalling WordPress :s